Read data from dynamic grid (or tool for manual creation of raster)
I made a tool for manual creation of raster image.
First cell code (after executing click the grid to paint custom image):
Style[Grid[
  Table[Toggler[
    0, {0 -> Checkbox[1, {1, 2, 3}], 1 -> Checkbox[3, {1, 2, 3}]}], 
   10, 10], Spacings -> {0.1, -0.4}], Selectable -> False, 
 Editable -> False]

Next cell code (execute to retrieve data from previous cell to create graphics):
NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]][[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] /. 
  TogglerBox[x_, _, _] -> x;
Graphics@Raster@Reverse@%

Is there a better method of retrieving the data from the grid without using NotebookRead?
I tried to set some variable like grid=Dynamic[Style[Grid[... but then the variable grid does not react to the changes made by clicking on the grid.


EDIT
I have suppressed a useless part of my code
EDIT END
You may be interested by this totally different approach :
grAdd = {};

ClickPane[
 Graphics[{Dynamic[Rectangle /@ grAdd]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 50}}
  , GridLines -> {Range[0, 50], Range[0, 50]}, 
  Frame -> True], (If[MemberQ[grAdd, Floor[#]]
    , grAdd = DeleteCases[grAdd, Floor[#]], 
    AppendTo[grAdd, Floor[#]]]) &]

Dynamic[grAdd]



Looks good. Should be 0 instead of -50 in your code.

Is there an easy way to adjust it also for mouse dragging for a free hand draw? Also I prefer the output as a raster.

Dragging to move a point or add points on the trajectory ?

Adding points on trajectory, do not bother too much, only if you see an easy adjustment, the code is already good as it is.

Converting to raster instead of using rectangles: raster = ConstantArray[1, {50, 50}]; (Part[raster, Sequence @@ (# + 1)] = 0) & /@ grAdd; Graphics@Raster@Transpose@raster

Another way to convert to a Raster : Graphics[Raster[Normal[SparseArray[# -> 0 & /@ grAdd, {50, 50}, 1]]]]

But should be # + 1 instead of #, the click pane starts at 0,0 array at 1,1.

Just use Dynamic.
Clear[x];

n = 10;
x[_, _] = 0;
Style[Grid[Table[With[{i = i, j = j}, 
    Toggler[Dynamic[x[i, j]], {0 -> Checkbox[1, {1, 2, 3}], 
      1 -> Checkbox[3, {1, 2, 3}]}]], {i, n}, {j, n}], 
  Spacings -> {0.1, -0.4}], Selectable -> False, Editable -> False]

Graphics@Raster@Reverse@Array[x, {n, n}]


That is what I wanted to avoid, using so much dynamic variables slows down response of the grid for larger n, say n=50. Isn't there a way to have one dynamic variable that contains the whole grid?
